# Preventing Mouse Wheel Event during Pointer Lock in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mousewheel, pointerlock

I want to prevent the mouse wheel from actually scrolling the document if the pointer is locked to a certain element.

Here is a minimal example:

```
<style>
    div {
        width: 200px;
        height: 2000px;
        background: red;
    }
</style>
<div></div>

<script>
    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    let locked = false;
    document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', () => {
        locked = document.pointerLockElement !== null;
        console.log("setting locked:", locked)
    });
    div.addEventListener('click', () => {
        div.requestPointerLock()
    });
    document.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
        if (!locked) {
            console.log("break");
            return;
        }

        console.log("locked:", locked, " cancelable:", event.cancelable);
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

When I click the red div the pointer is locked to the div (this works) and the variable `locked` is set to true (works). When I press ESC the lock is released and I can move the mouse again (works).

I also listen for mouse wheel events and prevent them if the variable `locked` is set to true. On Firefox and even Edge this works fine but on Google Chrome the `event.preventDefault()` is ignored and the page scrolls down/up (not what I want).

A sample workflow might look like this:

1. I move the cursor anywhere (over the div or not doesn't matter)
2. I use the scroll wheel and the page scrolls accordingly (as it should)
3. In the console I see `break`
4. Now I click on the div and the pointer is locked
5. The console says `setting locked: true`
6. Now I scroll again, but the page still scrolls (**wrong**)
7. Console: `locked: true  cancelable: false`

Now comes the interesting part: If I remove the `if (!locked) {}` section from the wheel event listener, the event **is** actually prevented while the console prints `locked: true  cancelable: true`.

So for some reason the `if` block makes the event non-cancelable?

**Here comes my question: How can I conditionally prevent the mouse wheel from scrolling the page, with the condition being whether the pointer is locked to a certain element?**

Some things I also tried:

- Attaching the wheel event listener to the `div`.
- Attaching an unconditionally preventing event listener when the pointer is locked and removing it when the lock is released.
- Attaching the wheel event listener to "everything": `window` `document` `div` ...
- `event.stopPropagation();`
- `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` (how many are there?)

All had the same outcome as the minimal example above.

**Edit:** I tried the minimal example on *Google Chrome 71* on *Windows 10* and on *Chromium 65* on *CentOS 7.4*: It didn't work there.

Comment: I tried your code and it IS preventing the wheel from scrolling the page.

Comment: @NickLee may I ask which browser you were using?

Comment: That was on chrome. I just tried it on a different version of chrome too and it works .